# Problema com ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilação

Estou com um erro de compilação no rails porém não dá para colocar todos os erros que aparece na tela do prompt de comando, mas nas linhas finais aparecem estas informações

> [NOTE]
>
> You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details:
> http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
> unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
> information.

minha versão do ruby - ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

minha versão do rails - Rails 5.1.4

Comment: Sem o log não dá pra ter certeza, mas parece ser um problema com ruby. Está usando Windows? Tente reinstalar.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado. Só por curiosidade o erro que estava dando está comentado, mais para baixo.

Answer (score 0):

O erro que está dando é este aqui.
maior_ou_menor.rb: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0001b0 (none) [FINISH]

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc) [0x7717E7AC]
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObject+0x12) [0x75A5EB42]
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\msvcrt-ruby230.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0xaa) [0x6305F9EA]
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\msvcrt-ruby230.dll(rb_bug_context+0x49) [0x62F06209]
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\msvcrt-ruby230.dll(rb_check_safe_obj+0x394) [0x62FD0794]
 [0x00401866]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlCaptureStackContext+0x1970d) [0x771B381D]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

- Loaded script: maior_ou_menor.rb
- Loaded features:

  0 enumerator.so
  1 thread.rb
  2 rational.so
  3 complex.so
  4 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
  5 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
  6 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/enc/windows_1252.so
  7 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/unicode_normalize.rb
  8 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
  9 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
  10 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
  11 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
  12 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/errors.rb
  13 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/version.rb
  14 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
  15 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/platform.rb
  16 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
  17 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
  18 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
  19 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/stringio.so
  20 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb
  21 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
  22 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
  23 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
  24 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
  25 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb
  26 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
  27 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb
  28 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
  29 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb
  30 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
  31 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
  32 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
  33 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkable.rb
  34 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/delegate.rb
  35 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
  36 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
  37 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
  38 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
  39 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
  40 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/formatter.rb
  41 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.